# Datetime automatically converts date at 00:00:00

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column that contains a date. I want to convert it to datetime, but when the hour is 00:00:00 it ignores the value and just displays the date. This is the code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(file_name)
print(df1["datetime"].head())
df1["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["datetime"],format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
print(df1["datetime"].head())
```

This is the output:

[image]

I want the datetime to mantain the 00:00:00. I am using Python 3.9.2

Comment: Just check the value of the specific cell using `print(df["datetime"].iat[0])` which should still have the time.

Comment: Based on the output `2021-07-20T00:00:00` it looks like there's a "T" in the datetime value. Try changing format to `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"`.

Comment: It works when printing, but when I save the data it deletes it. How should I save it then?

Comment: "save the data" - well, how are you saving the data?

Comment: It is saved into a csv file -> df1.to_csv(location, index= False)

Comment: If you verified that df1 is the way you want it before exporting to csv, then maybe your csv reader is ignoring the 00:00:00.  You can specify the format of the cells in your csv reader.  For me, Excel defaults to format m/d/yyyy h:mm (so the zeros show as 0:00), and if you use format m/d/yyyy you will not see any zeros, but you can specify format m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss to get 00:00:00

Comment: Thank you, I specified the format when saving the csv file and it worked.